# Allow submitter to choose who to submit a Cognito Form to

Tags: cognito-forms

I have edited the template for the PTO form in Cognito, but need the person filling out the form to be able to pick who the form is submitted to.

Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms. The form can currently only be submitted to one User/Organization name. In the future we do plan to add the ability to send notifications to specific users and email addresses. You can follow the specific progress for this on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/yC2e4U5M).

One work around for this would be to create a form for each manager or supervisor that the forms would be submitted to, then set the notification email to be sent to the specific person with the details showing. This can be done easily once you have created the first form. Using “Copy an existing form” located in the drop down from “+ New Form” will copy the base form you created. The new forms could then be titled to reflect what department or manager they are assigned to.

On your website you could then provide links to the different forms for users to select based on their department or manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can now create multiple email notifications and confirmations in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) and send them conditionally based on data on the form.  This would allow you to send notifications to different people based on form selections or even multiple different emails for a single submission.

You can also now send emails when updates occur while managing entries.  For example, you could configure the confirmation email to be sent when a PTO request is approved or denied with an appropriate message.  Internal Use fields are especially useful in this scenario.